# Parametrized uvm_events for uvm_sequence

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

In my verification environment, I have some common sequences set up for reusability:

```
    class common_sequence(type T = uvm_sequence) extends uvm_sequence#(uvm_sequence_item);

       `uvm_object_param_utils(common_sequence_t#(T))

       function new(string name="common_sequence");
          super.new(name);
       endfunction

       T sequence;

       virtual task body();
          `uvm_do(sequence);
       endtask
    endclass
```

I would like to create something similar where I can pass in an event.

```
    class common_sequence_with_event(type T = uvm_sequence, type E = uvm_event) extends uvm_sequence#(uvm_sequence_item);

       `uvm_object_param_utils(common_sequence_t#(T,E))

       function new(string name="common_sequence");
          super.new(name);
       endfunction

       T sequence;
       E event;

       virtual task body();
          event.wait_trigger();
          `uvm_do(sequence);
       endtask
    endclass
```

I would set this event from my test as follows:

```
class my_test extends uvm_test;
   `uvm_component_utils(my_test)
   uvm_event my_event;

   function new(string name = "my_test", uvm_component parent=null);
      super.new(name,parent);
   endfunction

   virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      super.build_phase(phase);

      uvm_event my_event = new ("my_event");
   endfunction

   virtual function void end_of_elaboration_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      super.end_of_elaboration_phase(phase);

      // Schedule sequences with sequencers
      uvm_config_db#(uvm_object_wrapper)::set(this,
                                              "env.my_agent.sequencer.reset_phase",
                                              "default_sequence",
                                              common_sequence#(reset_sequence)::get_type());

      uvm_config_db#(uvm_object_wrapper)::set(this,
                                              "env.my_agent.sequencer.main_phase",
                                              "default_sequence",
                                              common_sequence_with_event#(my_sequence, my_event )::get_type());

   endfunction

endclass
```

I get the compilation error: **class specialization parameter must be constant** for the common_sequence_with_event#(my_sequence, my_event) line.

I guess this means that parameters passed to classes must be a constant. So, in this case, why does it accept the reset_sequence which is also passed in as a parameter.

Also, is there a better way to do what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type parameters must be passed types. `my_event` is a variable, not a type. You did not show the declarations for `my_sequence` or `reset_sequence`, but I am assuming they are class types. Do you even need a parameter `E`? Won't it always be `uvm_event`?

Comment: my_sequence and reset_sequence are declared like any normal sequence:

my_sequence extends uvm_sequence(#transaction);

Comment: So all you need to do is remove the `type E` parameter declaration